# RWD flexbox form not working

Tags: css, checkbox

I have one simple question :

```css
html {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 
  }
  
  *,
  *:before,
  *:after {
 box-sizing: inherit;
  }
  
body  {
 background-image: url("IMG/tlo.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
 font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif; 
}   

.top-container {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 opacity: 0.42; 
 margin-top: 1rem;
}

.main-container {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-direction: column;
 max-height: 1200px;
 align-items: center;
 align-content: center;
 margin-top: 1.25rem;
 margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
 margin: 0 -5px;
 }

 .h2 {
 font-size: 2rem;
 text-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #2b0100;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 }

.rf-container  {
 display: flex;
 margin: 0 55px;
 width: 380px;
 background-color: #f4f4f4;
 padding: 20px 20px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
 }

 .form-rf {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 flex: 1;
 }

.rf-element  {
 display:flex;
 background-color: #f8f8f8;
 border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
 border-radius: 2px;
 margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
 height: 2.5rem;
 width: 340px;
}

.rf-element:hover {
 border-color: #88c814;
}

.main-icon {
 width: 45px;
 flex: 2;
 color: #dedede;
 font-size: 1.375rem;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 1%;
}

.main_field {
 flex: 10;
 height: 100%;
 border: none;
 background-color: #f8f8f8;
 font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1rem;
 color: #afafaf;
 padding-left: 3%;
 outline: none;
 border-style: none;
}

.main_field:focus {
 color: #428c42;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(204,204,204,0.9);
 border: 2px solid #a5cda5;
 background-color: #e9f3e9;
}

.separator {
 display: flex;
 width: 5px;
 min-height: 100%;
 background-color: #dedede;
 border-top: 0.1875rem solid #f8f8f8;
 border-bottom: 0.1875rem solid #f8f8f8;
}

 /*  checkbox */
.checkbox-custom {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;   
}

.checkbox-custom, .checkbox-custom-label {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0.3125rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox-custom-label{
    position: relative;
}

.checkbox-custom + .checkbox-custom-label:before{
    content: '';
    background: #fff;
    border: 0.125rem solid #ddd;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:1.25rem;
    height: 1.25rem;
    padding: 0.125rem;
    margin-right: 0.625rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.checkbox-custom:checked + .checkbox-custom-label:before {
    content: "";
    background: #428c42; 
}
 /*  checkbox end */

.main_green_button {
 margin-top: 0.5rem; 
 width: 100%;
 border: 0.0625rem solid #3b9a00;
 border-radius: 0.125rem;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-shadow: 0.0625rem 0.0625rem #51850e;
 background: linear-gradient(#a3d840, #73b618);
 height: 3rem;
 box-shadow: 0.0625rem 0.0625rem 0.0625rem 0px #FFFFFF;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.main_green_button:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(#AAE650, #7DC323);
}

.main_green_button_smaller {
 height: 2.1875rem;
 font-size: 1rem;
 width: 45%;
 
}

.main_green_button_smaller-disabled {
 opacity: 0.5;
 cursor: no-drop;
}

.main_green_button_smaller-warning {
 background: linear-gradient(#f65e70, #f03747);
 border: 1px rgba(209, 18, 18, 0.616);
}

.main_green_button_smaller-warning:hover {
 background: linear-gradient(#FF697D, #FA4155);
}

 /*  button  end */

 /*  text area*/

 .textarea {
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
 background-color: #f8f8f8;
 border: 0.0625rem solid #c6c6c6;
 border-radius: 1.5px;
 font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1rem;
 color: #afafaf;
 resize: none;
 }

 .doublebtn {
    display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 }


.footer {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 opacity: 0.5;
}

.footer_top {
  margin: 3.125rem 0px 0.5rem 0px;
  
}


 /*  MEDIA*/

 @media only screen and (max-width: 945px) {
 
 .main-container {
 
 max-height: 3100px;
 }
} 

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

 .main-container {
   margin: 0 auto;
 }

 .rf-container {
 margin: 0 auto;

 }
 .rf-element {
   
 }

 .main_field {
 
 }
 .doublebtn {
 
 }

}
```

```html
<section class="main-container">
  <!-- REGISTER FORM -->
    
  <h2 class="h2">Register Form</h2>
  <div class="rf-container">
         
   <form action="" class="form-rf">
    
    <!-- REGISTER FORM / 1 row -->
     <div class="rf-element">
      <div class="main-icon">
       <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="separator"></div>
      <input class="main_field" type="text" name="username"placeholder="Username" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Username'" required>
     </div>
    <!-- REGISTER FORM / 2 row -->          
     <div class="rf-element">
      <div class="main-icon">
       <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="separator"></div>
      <input class="main_field" type="password" name="password"placeholder="Password"
      onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Password'"  required>
     </div>    
    <!-- REGISTER FORM / 3 row --> 
     <div class="rf-element">
      <div class="main-icon">
       <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="separator"></div>
      <input class="main_field" type="password" name="Confirm Password"placeholder="Confirm Password" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Confirm Password'"  required>
     </div>    
    <!-- REGISTER FORM / 4 row --> 
     <div class="rf-element">
      <div class="main-icon">
       <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="separator"></div>
      <input class="main_field" type="email" name="Email"placeholder="Email" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Email'"  required>
     </div> 
    <!-- REGISTER FORM / 5 row --> 
     <div class="rf-element">
      <div class="main-icon">
       <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="separator"></div>
      <select class="main_field" name="location" required>
       <option value="" disabled selected>Your Location</option>
       <option value="gdansk">Gdańsk</option>
       <option value="krakow">Kraków</option>
       <option value="poznan">Poznań</option>
       <option value="warszawa">Warszawa</option>
       <option value="wroclaw">Wrocław</option>
      </select>      
     </div>     
    <!-- REGISTER FORM / 6 row --> 
    
    <input id="checkbox-1" class="checkbox-custom" name="checkbox-1" type="checkbox" >
    <label for="checkbox-1" class="checkbox-custom-label">I have read and accept the terms of use.</label>

    <!-- REGISTER FORM / sign in -->  
     <input class="main_green_button" type="submit" value="Sign up">       
    
         </form>
         
      </div>
   </section>
```

[codepen all](https://codepen.io/dudi1337/pen/OvjedE)

when I try make responsive,u see that forms do not fit on the page.
In fact, no element is responsive despite the use FLEXBOX.

I tried to combine using values `flex: 1 1 auto;` or `flex: 1 1 80%` an excuse for `.main-field  input` .

In short - I would like to receive responsive forms, but at the moment I have no idea how to deal with it.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: hmm,  them  just watch  this on  280px size and u  see what im  asking for.

Comment: So what are your expecting to happen when you define `width: 380px;`? flex box will not make this smaller. That's what media queries are for.